# Global exception handling and Logging in asp.net MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to asp.net core mvc. i need to write Global exception handling and error Logging  in on palce..i dont need to write all below in every controller Please help me to write globally in one place

Here is the my code

using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace NS.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        static ILogger _logger;
        public HomeController(ILoggerFactory factory)
        {
            if (_logger == null)
                _logger = factory.Create("Unhandled Error");
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var error = feature?.Error;
            _logger.LogError("Oops!", error);
            return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml", error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");` in `Configure()` method

Comment: Thanks..i dont want to write  public IActionResult Error(){} in each controller ..is thery any method write Error function  globally?

Comment: It's working global in your app. When you get exception `UseExceptionHandler()` catch it and redirect to indicated controller and action. So in fact you can use  single `ErrorController` with `Error` action.

Comment: Ok,,thanks a lot for quick reply..

Comment: Please keep in mind, there is no MVC6 yet. Only ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0 & 1.1

Comment: ok,.Thanks @Tseng...Will this works for all error codes like 500 / 404 erros? or we have to write seperate handling mechanism?Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Startup.cs` using `.UseExceptionHandler()`  you can set route to your error action:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

}
```

Here you find more : [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)